# Invalid operands to binary == error

Tags: c, arrays, indexing

```
intarr_result_t intarr_set( intarr_t* ia, 
                unsigned int index, 
                int val )
{
    if( ia[index] != NULL )
    {
        index = val;
        return INTARR_OK;
    }
    else if (ia[index] == NULL)
    {
        return INTARR_BADARRAY;
    }
    else
    {
        return INTARR_BADINDEX;
    }
}
```

This function is supposed to return INTARR_OK if an index is valid, and I set the ia[index] value to val.  If ia is null, I return INTARR_BADARRAY, and otherwise, I leave the array unmodified and return INTARR_BADINDEX.  But when I ran this code, I got the following errors:

```
intarr.c:37:16: error: invalid operands to binary != (have ‘intarr_t’ and ‘void *’)
  if( ia[index] != NULL )
                ^
intarr.c:42:21: error: invalid operands to binary == (have ‘intarr_t’ and ‘void *’)
  else if (ia[index] == NULL)
```

Does anybody know what this error means?

The definition of intarr_t:

```
typedef struct {
  int* data;
  unsigned int len;
} intarr_t;
```

Comment: It means `intarr_t` is not a pointer.  Post the definition of `intarr_t`.

Comment: @chux But on the function parameters, I already put intarr_t* though.  Unless i have to do something else to the ia[index]

Comment: Yes, intarr_t* means ia is an array of intarr_t; so ia[index] is an intarr_t, not (apparently) a pointer.

Comment: If you do not post the definition of `intarr_t`, answers will tell you what _not_ to do.  If you post the definition of `intarr_t`, you may get an example correct code.

Comment: @chux Yeah sorry I just added the definition of intarr_t.  It's a struct.

Comment: @user3880587 So now you have it: cannot compare a pointer to a structure.  Described the purpose of the structure  (oops I see you have done some of that).  Looks like you want to set `ia[index].data` and `ia[index].len` to something.

Comment: @user3880587 1) `intarr_set()` does not have the info needed to determine if `index` is valid. 2) Code should be `if (ia == NULL) { return INTARR_BADARRAY;` and that `if()` should be first.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what an intarr_t is, but if it's an int, you can compare it not to NULL but to 0; if it's a char, you can compare it not to NULL but to '\0'.

The message means that NULL is the null pointer, and intarr_t is apparently not a pointer, so there is a type conflict.

So now that you've posted intarr_t -- when is it invalid?  maybe you need

```
if (ia[index].data != NULL)
```

Comment: Note: An `int` and a `char` can compare to `0` or `'\0'`.  Both `0` or `'\0'` are `int`.

Comment: True.  I'm compulsive.

Answer (score 0):

OP is trying to compare a pointer (NULL) to a structure `intarr_t` which does not work.

Appears function should be more like the below.  Need to pass in the number of elements in the array.  Further need to convert `int val` to a string for `.data`.

```
intarr_result_t intarr_set(intarr_t* ia, unsigned NumElement, 
    unsigned index, int val ) {
  if (ia == NULL) {
    return INTARR_BADARRAY;
  }
  if( index >= NumElement) {
    return INTARR_BADINDEX;
  }
  char buffer[50];
  sprintf(buffer, "%d", val);
  ia[index].len = strlen(buffer);
  ia[index].data = strdup(buffer);
  return INTARR_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the same concept mistake: in your case `ia` is a pointer but not `ia[index]`, indeed `ia[index]` is and instance of `intarr_t` struct.

To solve the problem you have to use `&` in this way:

```
if(&ia[index] != NULL)
{
    ...
}
```

I hope I was helpful.